# Select duplicates while concatenating every one except the first

Tags: mysql

I am trying to write a query that will select all of the numbers in my table, but those numbers with duplicates i want to append something on the end that shows it as a duplicate. However I am not sure how to do this.

Here is an example of the table

```
TableA
ID      Number
1       1
2       2
3       2
4       3
5       4
```

SELECT statement output would be like this.

```
Number
1
2
2-dup
3
4
```

Any insight on this would be appreciated.

Comment: Really, both `2` values should be marked as duplicates, no? Are there any other fields that distinguish one `2` record from the other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you mysql version didn't support window function. you can try to write a subquery to make row_number then use `CASE WHEN` to judgement `rn > 1` then mark `dup`.

```
create table T (ID int, Number int);


INSERT INTO T VALUES  (1,1);
INSERT INTO T VALUES  (2,2);
INSERT INTO T VALUES  (3,2);
INSERT INTO T VALUES  (4,3);
INSERT INTO T VALUES  (5,4);
```

**Query 1**:

```
select t1.id,
       (CASE WHEN rn > 1 then CONCAT(Number,'-dup') ELSE Number END) Number
from (
  SELECT *,(SELECT COUNT(*) 
            FROM T tt 
            where tt.Number = t1.Number and tt.id <= t1.id
           ) rn
  FROM T t1
)t1
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/34c8e/10/0)**:

```
| id | Number |
|----|--------|
|  1 |      1 |
|  2 |      2 |
|  3 |  2-dup |
|  4 |      3 |
|  5 |      4 |
```

If you can use *window function* you can use `row_number` with *window function* to make `rownumber` by `Number`.

```
select t1.id,
       (CASE WHEN rn > 1 then CONCAT(Number,'-dup') ELSE Number END) Number
from (
  SELECT *,row_number() over(partition by Number order by id) rn
  FROM T t1
)t1
```

[sqlfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6kYtAwtcHQ9qDfb8382iLq/0)

Comment: This logic work, thanks for the help. Took me a bit to work it in to a larger query.

Answer (score 0):

I made a list of all the IDs that weren't dups (left join select) and then compared them to the entire list(case when):

`select
case when a.id <> b.min_id then cast(a.Number as varchar(6)) + '-dup' else cast(a.Number as varchar(6)) end as Number
from table_a
left join (select MIN(b.id) min_id, Number from table_a b group by b.number)b on b.number = a.number`

I did this in MS SQL 2016, hope it works for you.

This creates the table used:

`insert into table_a (ID, Number)
select 1,1
union all 
select 2,2
union all 
select 3,2
union all 
select 4,3
union all 
select 5,4`